# gganimate: Transition between states with static lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am trying to create a gif of per-hour road network volumes using the following code.

```
require(sf)
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)
require(RColorBrewer)
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)

atl_dt <- fread("Documents/all_links.csv", stringsAsFactors = F, header = T)
all_links1 <- st_as_sf(atl_dt, wkt="WKT")
st_crs(all_links1) <- 5070


test <- ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = all_links1, aes(color=link_volume)) + 
  scale_color_distiller(palette = "OrRd", direction = 1) +
  ggtitle("hour-of-day:{frame_time}") +
  transition_time(as.integer(departure_hour)) +
  ease_aes("linear") +
  enter_fade() +
  exit_fade()

# save as a GIF
animate(test, fps = 10, width = 750, height = 450)
anim_save("Documents/test1.gif")
```

This gives me the following gif. As you can see, the road links seem to be moving randomly before getting rearrnaged at every hour which makes the gif very murky and difficult to analyze. How do I avoid this and just show the changes the link volumes (using the color gradient) without making the links move for every hour?

[image]

Full data available from the [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/powp3ev93wucj7c/all_links.csv?dl=0).

Comment: Can you provide some data?

Comment: Sample data provided. Please let me know if you need the full file.

Comment: You are using  ```departure_hour``` in transition_time, but it is uniquely 12 or 13. Is there a better variable for time? (I'm not getting a gif to run on my machine, btw. I don't know why.)

Comment: Clarifying: ```departure_hour``` is uniquely 12 or 13 in the subset you provided. It seems like a lot of data, but may not include much that animates?

Comment: Yes. The number of links were too low and the animation wasn't really readable. I updated the code to read the full data and also provided a link to the full data (about 5 mb).

Comment: no one else has access to your local files but you, there is not way I can read "Documents/all_links.csv" unless you post it somewhere online like Dropbox or Gdrive

Comment: I already posted the dropbox link. Please look at the last line in the post.

Comment: I tried a couple of things and didn't get anything really different. I slowed the fps way down, but see pretty much the same thing - within the same hour, a clear view of, I guess, lots of cell links to cars on the highways, but then switching out to the non-highway links. The data seems not to be consistently reflecting the same phenomenon. Just my guess.

Comment: I think it has to do more with the effects. Between every time step, the links randomly move around and reassemble. This reassembling is probably included to make it look cool but it doesn't work for this type of figure and really messes it up. You will see the links slowly moving around if you increase the fps to either 50 or 100.

Comment: It looks like you need to add a `group = ???` term to your `aes()` call, so that gganimate can know which points are supposed to stay in place. Is there a variable or two that relate(s) to location which you could use for that?